# Redis - list of visited sites from crawler

Tags: python, url, redis, queue, web-crawler

I'm currently working on a crawler coded in Python with combination of Gevent/requests/lxml to crawl a defined set of pages. I use redis as a db to hold lists such as pending queue, fetching, and sites that has been crawled. For each url, I have a key url_ and I'm using a SETNX command to ensure that the URL has not been already crawled and then put it into the queue.

One of the problems that I'm starting to face is that the url_ set of keys are starting to **grow really fast** and Redis keep almost all data in memory so it will soon become an issue. The URL that are crawled don't have an expiration time as I need to visit them only once and the content of the url will not change in the future so I still want to keep all visited urls. (There are a lot of duplicate URLs that I'm filtering) Is it possible to use some data structure like cuckoo hash table or bloom filter in Redis so I can prevent the list of visited urls to be growing that fast and still benefit the speed when quering the queue?

Is there some alternative approach that I can use to determine if the URL has been already visited or not? The solution should be scalable and distributed as the crawlers are currently running on more than one machine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Look into using Redis' (2.8.9+) [HyperLogLog data structure](http://redis.io/commands#hyperloglog) - you can use `PFADD` and `PFCOUNT` to get a reasonable answer whether a URL was counted before.
2. Don't keep each URL in its own `url_` key - consolidate into a single or bucket Hashs as explained in ["Memory Optimization/Using hashes to abstract a very memory efficient plain key-value store on top of Redis"](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis)
3. Store the visited URLs in a single (a several bucketed) Sets for history lookup and autodeduplication. Use a Sorted Set with a URL's score set to the epoch value of its crawl time to have them ordered and do range queries.

Bottom line: unless you're using `url_` keys to actually store something about the URL, don't go that way. It seems that you're using these keys just to manage a state so Hashes and Sets would be more efficient and robust.

Comment: I managed to use bucket hashes on redis + mongodb side as filters which greatly reduced the memory storage required.